# Changing Profile Picture upload name?

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading, profile

I need some help, I am trying to get it where once someone uploads an image, it will change it to their username. Here is some of the PHP Script that I have that uploads the image by the name that the file originally is.

So once they login it automatically says their username, Which i used 
 $_SESSION['username'] how do I use that so once they choose a photo it will save it as their username. example : I'm uploading a file called logo.png and my username is admin. How do I do it where it will change the file name to admin.png instead of logo.png?

`//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()){ header('Location: login.php'); }
?>
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
</code>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey I guess you just need to change your `$target_file` variable... try like this:

```
.....
$target_file = basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION); //IMAGE FILE TYPE
$fileName = $_SESSION['username'].'.'. $imageFileType; //GENERATE FILE NAME

....//then when you move the file

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir.$fileName)
```

As you can see I changed the `$target_file` to `$fileName` and added the `$target_dir`

Than should be ok!

Comment: awesome!!! mark the answer as correct so if someone has the same problem can see it :)